# Minimizing Sum of Least Squares in Matlab

Tags: optimization, matlab, least-squares

I am working on this minimization problem for image warping that I want to solve in Matlab:
[image]

Each feature $p$ can be presented by a 2D bilinear interpolation of the four vertices $V_p = [v_p^1, v_p^2, v_p^3, v_p^4]$ of the enclosing grid cell: $p = V_p w_p$, where $w_p = [w_p^1, w_p^2, w_p^3, w_p^4]^T$. We expect that the corresponding point $\hat p$ can be represented by the same weights of the warped grid vertices $\hat V_p = [\hat v_p^1, \hat v_p^2, \hat v_p^3, \hat v_p^4]$. We have the first term to minimize:
$$E_d(\hat V) = \sum_p||\hat V_p w_p - \hat p||$$
Where $\hat V$ contains all the warped grid vertices.

We also have a second term to minimize:
$$E(\hat V) = \sum_{\hat v}||\hat v - \hat v_1 - sR_{90}(\hat v_0 - \hat v_1) ||^2;  R_{90} = \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix} and s = ||v-v_1||/||v_0-v_1||$$

So the final energy to minimize is:
$$E(\hat V) = E_d(\hat V) + E_s(\hat V)$$
I am trying to minimize this function in Matlab with the unknowns are the positions of the vertices $\hat v_i$ but I am not making any progress. Is there any hints or ways to simply the minimization problem to be solved in Matlab ?
Thank you.

Comment: In Matlab, you could use `fminsearch` or `fminunc`. If you only supply the function to minimize, those functions use order zero methods like Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm. You could choose to supply the function and the gradient of the function. In that case, these functions use order one methods like trust-region algorithms or gradient descent.

Comment: Thank you this can be a good start. The thing bothering me is how to write the function to minimize in term of the $\hat v$. Because each vertex is present in 4 grid cells which makes it unclear how to write the function in term of the output vertices position